# How to give a function a specific column of a list using a for-loop but prevent that output is named according to the iterator command

Tags: r

Given the following example:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure = "RR", ai = tpos, bi = tneg, ci = cpos, di = cneg, data = dat.bcg, append = TRUE)
dat
rma(yi, vi, data = dat, mods = ~dat[[8]], subset = (alloc=="systematic"), knha = TRUE)


   trial               author year tpos  tneg cpos  cneg ablat      alloc      yi     vi
1      1              Aronson 1948    4   119   11   128    44     random -0.8893 0.3256
2      2     Ferguson & Simes 1949    6   300   29   274    55     random -1.5854 0.1946
3      3      Rosenthal et al 1960    3   228   11   209    42     random -1.3481 0.4154
4      4    Hart & Sutherland 1977   62 13536  248 12619    52     random -1.4416 0.0200
5      5 Frimodt-Moller et al 1973   33  5036   47  5761    13  alternate -0.2175 0.0512
6      6      Stein & Aronson 1953   NA    NA   NA    NA    44  alternate      NA     NA
7      7     Vandiviere et al 1973    8  2537   10   619    19     random -1.6209 0.2230
8      8           TPT Madras 1980  505 87886  499 87892    NA     random  0.0120 0.0040
9      9     Coetzee & Berjak 1968   29  7470   45  7232    27     random -0.4694 0.0564
10    10      Rosenthal et al 1961   17  1699   65  1600    42 systematic -1.3713 0.0730
11    11       Comstock et al 1974  186 50448  141 27197    18 systematic -0.3394 0.0124
12    12   Comstock & Webster 1969    5  2493    3  2338    33 systematic  0.4459 0.5325
13    13       Comstock et al 1976   27 16886   29 17825    33 systematic -0.0173 0.0714
```

Now what i basically want is to iterate with the rma() command (only for mods argument) from - let's say - [7:8] and to store this result in a variable equal to the columnname.

Two problems:

1) When i enter the command:

```
rma(yi, vi, data = dat, mods = ~dat[[8]], subset = (alloc=="systematic"), knha = TRUE)
```

The modname is named as dat[[8]]. But I want the modname to be the columname (i.e. `colnames(dat[i])`)

```
Model Results:

          estimate      se     tval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub   
intrcpt     0.5543  1.4045   0.3947  0.7312  -5.4888  6.5975   
dat[[8]]   -0.0312  0.0435  -0.7172  0.5477  -0.2185  0.1560
```

2) Now imagine that I have a lot of columns more and I want to iterate from [8:53], such that each result gets stored in a variable named equal to the columnname.

---

Problem 2) has been solved:

```
for(i in 7:8){
assign(paste(colnames(dat[i]), i, sep=""), rma(yi, vi, data = dat, mods = ~dat[[i]], subset = (alloc=="systematic"), knha = TRUE))}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answers 1st part of your question, you can change the names by accessing the attributes of the model object.
In this case

```
# inspect the attributes
attr(model$vb, which = "dimnames")
# assign the name
attr(model$vb, which = "dimnames")[[1]][2] <- paste(colnames(dat)[8])
```